# How to display and edit previously added details when i click on edit option in my webpage written in PHP?

Tags: php

In my webpage after clicking on edit option in the action menu the webpage

- It should display the previous inserted details and facility to edit that old value
- to make changes and reinsert again.

Comment: First read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question!

Comment: What are you editing, a database value?

Comment: The values come from a Database??

Comment: @EternalHour I am editing the activity page and it should display the value previously inserted to the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When click on edit button..You have to set a link having the id of the user you want to edit...like www.xyz.com?id=5

Then get that id using $_GET and make a query to get information for that user having id 5...Then load a view or a php page and embed that information in that page...i mean in form controls like text,select etc.

Comment: I will try this and let u know about the result..

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: Not yet bro..I will let u know if any...

Comment: ohk dear...feel free to contact :)

Comment: yeah sure bro...  :)